# how to draw this ? Square blank BlackSquare in unicode

Tags: unicode

I would like to draw this : ■■■□□

But it's not easy i would like the square to have the same size.

And it's difficult to search about it with google.

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left side: unicodes. Right side: `unicode-math` commands. Below: other possibilities (QED just yields a real square in Latin Modern Math, Cambria Math, Asana Math and TeX Gyre Pagella Math).

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}    
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\[\symbol{"025AA} \smblksquare\]
\[\symbol{"025AB} \smwhtsquare\]
\[\symbol{"025A0} \mdlgblksquare\]
\[\symbol{"025A1} \mdlgwhtsquare\]
\[\symbol{"025FB} \mdwhtsquare\]
\[\symbol{"025FC} \mdblksquare\]
\[\symbol{"025FD} \mdsmwhtsquare\]
\[\symbol{"025FE} \mdsmblksquare\]
\[\symbol{"02B1B} \lgblksquare\]
\[\symbol{"02B1C} \lgwhtsquare\]

\[\QED \vee \blockfull\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

▪ ▫ ▪ ▫ ▪ ▫ ▪ ▫ ▪ ▫ ▪ ▫

U+25AA and U+25AB

Comment: how to print it ? i've tried but it prints me only U+25AA regards

Comment: @user462794 you asked for unicode so I was assuming you were using xetex or luatex ? and then you can just use the characters you can use ▪ ▫ just as you'd use A B. If you want to refer to it by number you could use `^^^^25aa` and `^^^^25ab`